# Getting vehicle current edge ID

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to get vehicle current edge id as follow:

```
mobility = Veins::TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
assert(mobility);
traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
string cur=traciVehicle->getRoadId();
```

But it returns an invalid edge id, and the same for the lane id.
What is wrong? Is there another way to get edge id?

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
string cur = mobility->getRoadId();
```